# error during transfer issue when initial mmc card in U-Boot

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot

how should i debug the **error during transfer** when i init mmc card by send **uboot** command: **mmc rescan** ? this bug only when i init mmc card, SD card won't happen. Though this warning happened, but the response looks like OK.

thanks

mmc_send_cmd: error during transfer: 0x00408001
mmc_send_cmd: error during transfer: 0x00208001
mmc_send_cmd: error during transfer: 0x00108001

=================================================================================

```
CURR STATE:4                                                                    
CMD_SEND:8                                                                      
            ARG                      0x00000000                             
            FLAG                     0                                      
mmc_send_cmd: error during transfer: 0x00208001                                 
            MMC_RSP_R1,5,6,7         0x00000900                             
CMD_SEND:6                                                                      
            ARG                      0x03B70000                             
            FLAG                     0                                      
            MMC_RSP_R1b              0x7FFBF590                             
CMD_SEND:13                                                                     
            ARG                      0x00000000                             
            FLAG                     0                                      
            MMC_RSP_R1,5,6,7         0x00000900                             
CURR STATE:4                                                                    
CMD_SEND:16                                                                     
            ARG                      0x00000200                             
            FLAG                     0                                      
            MMC_RSP_R1,5,6,7         0x00000900                             
CMD_SEND:17                                                                     
            ARG                      0x00000000                             
            FLAG                     0                                      
mmc_send_cmd: error during transfer: 0x00108001                                 
            MMC_RSP_R1,5,6,7         0x00000900                             
ORIGEN #
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Solutions must be posted as answers (NOT updates to the question) even if it is your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i have been move the answer to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer after survey more webpages,

**error during transfer** means that time-out error happened while read from storage.

1) For check H/W side
Can you try again after re-connect the CPU board?
Connection of CPU board can be loosen during delivery.

2) For check S/W side
I'd like to ask for make sure, did you use our bootloader?
Previous version of Linaro's bootloader can happen those thing depend on situation.

If you still have problem then it might be eMMC problem.

more over, this error code(TIMEOUT) is -19